# Display in asc order from multiple databases under multiple linked server and add two date parameters so that I can integrate it to my app

Tags: sql-server, subquery, scripting

I have a script below where it display a result from different databases under different linked Server. The query is just connected or linked thru union all and it seems there's no issue on its result. My only problem is I want to display the result in desc order by using the read-rate higher result regardless which linked server it came from. I have an idea if its possible to use the ff script to convert into subquery, but I don't know how I am able to use it with join also. See Script below:

```sql
SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER1].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER1].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

UNION ALL

SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER2].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER2].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

UNION ALL

SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER3].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER3].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

UNION ALL

SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER4].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER4].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName
```

example RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to return the results in a different order?

Comment: I just want the read-rate column to sort  in desc order.

Comment: @Caspersky12, have you tried adding `ORDER BY ReadRate DESC` to the end of the query?

Comment: @DanGuzman I mean, order by  as a whole since those query were getting results from different linked-server and different database, I can put order by on every select statement after group by, but I think the result could be on that particular select statement only.

Comment: other way to achieve this, is by creating a view let say I copy paste those script and add on top of the script as Create view VwAllZones, after creation I can use select statement like select top 25 * from VwAllZones order by ReadRate desc.

Comment: The final `ORDER BY ReadRate DESC` will order all of the concatenated `UNION ALL` results, not just the final query.

Comment: Side note: `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` isn't so great with indexes, try `WHERE TRXN_DATE >= CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND TRXN_DATE < DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dan pointed out in the comments, when you add an `ORDER BY` clause to the last query in a `UNION ALL` (or `UNION`) clause, the engine is smart enough to know you want the entire results of that `UNION ALL` clause to be ordered that way.

So to accomplish your goal of ordering the results by the `ReadRate` column, all you need is a final `ORDER BY` clause like so:

```
SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER1].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER1].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

UNION ALL

SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER2].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER2].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

UNION ALL

SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER3].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER3].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

UNION ALL

SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
FROM [LINKED-SERVER4].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN
[LINKED-SERVER4].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName
ORDER BY ReadRate DESC
```

Notice how the `ORDER BY` clause references an alias instead of column, showing that it means the entire result set, not just that specific query.

If you want to do extra coding to feel warm and fuzzy about it (aka make it more readable to future developers perhaps) then you can just wrap your query in parenthesis to make it a subquery, and then you can apply the `ORDER BY` clause to the outside of the subquery like so:

```
SELECT TrxnDTime, PlazaCode, PlazaName, Lane, Zone, TotalRead, TotalManual, TotalCount, ReadRate
FROM
(
    SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
    FROM [LINKED-SERVER1].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN
    [LINKED-SERVER1].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
    GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
    FROM [LINKED-SERVER2].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN
    [LINKED-SERVER2].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
    GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
    FROM [LINKED-SERVER3].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN
    [LINKED-SERVER3].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
    GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT        TRXN_DATE AS TrxnDTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Plaza) PlazaCode, t2.PlazaName, Lane, t2.Zone, SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalRead, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) TotalManual, SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ) TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_READ))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SUM(TOTAL_MANUAL) + SUM(TOTAL_READ))) * 100) AS ReadRate 
    FROM [LINKED-SERVER4].[Database1].DBO.Table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN
    [LINKED-SERVER4].[Database1].DBO.Table2 t2 ON t1.Plaza = t2.PlazaCode
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRXN_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND t1.Plaza > 0
    GROUP BY TRXN_DATE, Plaza, Lane, t2.Zone, t2.PlazaName
) AS Results
ORDER BY ReadRate DESC
```

Comment: thank you J.D and Dan and the rest for the help

Comment: @Caspersky12 NP! Cheers!